# ModuleNotFoundError when converting from .py to .exe

Tags: python, tkinter, exe, autopy

I created a program in Pycharm which uses the following library:

```
import sys
sys.coinit_flags = 2
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog, ttk, messagebox
import os
import zipfile
import shutil
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller
from pywinauto import application
import time
```

When I run it in Pycharm, everything works fine. I want to be able to share the script with my colleagues who will not have Python on their desktop, so I wanted to change the .py file to an .exe. For this I used `auto-py-to-exe`. However after the .exe file was made, it wouldn't run and gave me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "unzipper.py", line 18, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pynput'
[2076] Failed to execute script unzipper
```

I read through the documentations on the [auto-py-to-exe errors](https://nitratine.net/blog/post/issues-when-using-auto-py-to-exe/?utm_source=auto_py_to_exe&utm_medium=application_link&utm_campaign=auto_py_to_exe_help&utm_content=bottom#how-to-fix-specific-issues). And as I tried the fix for the ModuleNotFoundError, I'm still getting the same error.

[image: Hidden import]

Wondering if anyone knows how to fix this. Just as additional info, I'm using Python 3.8

edit:

I've also tried to install it manually using pyinstaller. But still no luck. The .py file would run perfectly, but the .exe would give this error:

[image: error]

Comment: Whats there on line 18, in your code?

Comment: root.title("Unzip")

Comment: Not sure why this is happening though